# Is there an upper cap on the number of partitions in Apache Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I have read that its 10000. But what i want to know is that this limit is on 1 broker or the entire cluster.
I want to have a topic with event name and capture all the event streams of the user. Now i wish to record activity to every user on the dedication partition where that particular user's event will go.
Now what if the number of users go beyond 10000. Can i increase the number of partitions just by adding another broker or this approach is not feasible at all.

Answer (score 3):

First of all there is a nice post about Kafka Partitions on [Confluent blog](http://www.confluent.io/blog/how-to-choose-the-number-of-topicspartitions-in-a-kafka-cluster/) by one of the author of Kafka. Maybe it will help you.

I don't think it's a good idea to create a partition for each user. Besides other things it's hard to dynamically add new partitions to Kafka cluster and I suppose you would need it. What is the main reason for such architecture?

I think It should be sufficient to use let's say ten partitions and you can send to every partition data of 1000 users. When you read the messages you will always know to which user the message belongs because there would be some `userId`. You just need to ensure that two events from the same user will end up in the same partition. That's all.

Hope it helps, Lukas

Comment: the doc doest tell not to put 1000 partitions per topic or any thumb rule on number of partitions per topic. He only says having 1000 partitions adds 20 ms additional commit time

Answer (score 2):

This question is a bit old, but there is a lot of confusion around this issue.

The answer is closely related to the version of the Kafka broker that you are running. As you can see in this [Apache blog post](https://blogs.apache.org/kafka/entry/apache-kafka-supports-more-partitions), a reasonably up to date cluster can hold up to **4,000** partitions per broker and up to **200,000** partitions in a cluster.

Comment: This doesn't give a number per topic, though

Answer (score 0):

> wish to record activity to every user on the dedication partition where that particular user's event will go.

I highly suggest not doing this, as you probably don't have any control over number of users in your system.

Instead, partition by user ID, but create as many topics as you think will scale. For example, with alphanumeric ids, you get regex pattern `[a-zA-Z0-9]`, which can be partitioned across `2*26 + 10 = 62` partitions with just one character. Expand to two characters, and you get `62*62 = 3844` partitions. However, as other answer to Apache blog indicates, you'll be near the top of recommend limit of partitions per broker. These are controlled by OS file handles, more than Kafka itself.

This way, given a user ID, you'll always know exactly which partition they exist in, if you run into consumer issues.

> Can i increase the number of partitions just by adding another broker

That's not how you increase partitions, so no